# Js check if string is in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have string:

```
var str = "Overweek,Next 14 days";
```

And array:

```
var arr=["Next 14 days","Next month"];
```

How can I check if at leads one part of str (Overweek and Next 14 days) is in array. 
I tried it:

```
$.inArray(str,array);
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I solve it?

Comment: When you say "at least one part of str" you need to define what a part is.  How many characters are a "part"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Array.prototype.some` and `String.prototype.includes`:

```js
var str = "Overweek,Next 14 days";
var arr=["Next 14 days","Next month"];
let found = arr.some(needle => str.includes(needle));
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(jQuery.inArray("Overweek", arr) !== -1){
   alert('IN ARRAY')
}
```

I'm not sure what you want, but you can split your string by commas and then iterate over this new array word by word and do your original check like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `some` (as in the other answer) or you could use `String.protoype.includes.apply` as shown below:

```js
var str = "Overweek,Next 14 days";
var arr=["Next 14 days","Next month"];

console.log(String.prototype.includes.apply(str, arr)); // true
console.log(String.prototype.includes.apply(str, ['yesterday', 'tomorrow'])); // false
console.log(String.prototype.includes.apply(str, ['Next 14 days', 'tomorrow'])); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

split your `str` then loop

```
var str = "Overweek,Next 14 days";
var arr=["Next 14 days","Next month"];
$(str.split(',')).each(function(index, item){
  if($.inArray(item, arr) > -1)
    alert(item);
});
```